# How to download multiple URLs over and over again in parallel in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small IoT setup at home and need to repeatedly query a small number of RESTful APIs to obtain data from multiple sensors. Every URL needs to be queried using a custom delay between different tries.

What's the best way to implement this in Node.JS? The ultimate goal is to parse returned JSON and persist in the Realm DB.

I'm trying to implement this on promises and struggling to come up with two things: 1) where should I put then() to handle the server's response (simulated as setTimeout), 2) how to reschedule the URL after timeout.

```
const conf = [
  {
    url: "http://google.com",
    timeout: 2400, // ms between queries
  },
  {
    url: "http://duckduckgo.com",
    timeout: 2000,
  }
];

let activePromises = [];

conf.forEach( function(el) {
  activePromises.push( new Promise(
    function webHandler(resolve, reject) {
      console.log(`Starting request to ${ el.url }...`);
      setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(`Resolving ${ el.url } after ${ el.timeout }ms`);
        resolve('body'); // real-world contents will be a JSON document
        // how to repeat the same API query after el.timeout ms???
      }, 30);
    }
  ));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all()` along with `map()`

```
const conf = [
 {
   url: "http://google.com",
   timeout: 2400, // ms between queries
 },
 {
   url: "http://duckduckgo.com",
   timeout: 2000,
 }
];

Promise.all(conf.map(async item=> await doTask(item.url,item.timeout)))

const doTask=(url,timeout)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
   ..... 
 }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't show how to actually handle different timeout per promise, has useless new Promise constructor that shouldn't be there and `Promise.all` is used for no reason at all

Answer (score 0):

If you have to repeat the action every n seconds you are looking for setInterval

```
const conf = [
  {
    url: "http://google.com",
    timeout: 2400, // ms between queries
  },
  {
    url: "http://duckduckgo.com",
    timeout: 2000,
  }
];

const fetchResult = url => api(url) //pseudo code here

let results = Array(conf.length).fill(Promise.resolve(null))

conf.foreach(({url, timeout}, i) => {
  setInterval(async() => {
    const res =  await fetchResult(url)
    results[i] = res;
  }, timeout)
})
```

in the results array you have n promises.
Then you can use Promise.all if you like or treat them separately

Comment: how would one use constantly mutating array of promises you are referring to? when do you want to call Promise.all?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say (for simplicity) `loadData` is the function that will fetch data from the URL (which you have currently simulated using timeout).

If you want to start sending requests at regular intervals, you can simply use setInterval:

```js
conf.forEach(el => {
   setInterval(() => {
      loadData(el.url)
         .then((body) => { /** Save to DB here */ });
         .catch(() => { /** Handle error */ });
   }, el.timeout);
});
```

But if you want to wait till loadData resolves, and then wait for the timeout duration, you can do something like:

```js
function process() {
   loadData(el.url).then((body) => {
      /** Save to DB here */
      setTimeout(process, el.timeout);
   }).catch(() => { /** Handle error */ });
}
```

which will call the same function after the specified timeout duration.

Comment: Your first example is correct. Second example should account for arbitrary number of `then`s before `setTimeout` as saving to db is an asynchronous task. Most importantly, `setTimeout` is not a recursion and will not increase call stack

Comment: @Max thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of the concept of async stacks, and when I executed this and viewed in dev tools, thought it was the actual call stack. I have edited my answer.